# Retracting flags on comments

Tags: discussion

I'm guessing there is no way of doing this? I flagged a comment by mistake, and now am unable to retract it =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to retract a flag... you may be able to add another, or just add a comment to the effect that it should be ignored and we'll likely see that when reviewing the flag. You could even flag your own new comment to make sure we see it :)